# SocketIO on a Node.js cluster

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cluster-computing

I have a standalone Node.js app which has SocketIO server that listens on a certain port, e.g. 8888. Now I am trying to run this app in a cluster and because cluster randomly assigns workers to requests, SocketIO clients in XHR polling mode once handshaken and authorized with one worker get routed to another worker where they're not handshaken and the mess begins.

And because workers don't share anything, I can't find a workaround. Is there a known solution to this issue?

Comment: do you really need socket.io and request polling? You can just use ws.

Comment: in our case socketio clients may be on devices that don't have reliable HTTP connection, e.g. http://teradek.com/pages/bond, so ws won't always work - xhr-polling is more reliable

Comment: This is still an unsolved issue with socket.io 
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/952
He hints to add timeout to the http-upgrade part to mitigate it

Answer (score 1):

There is no "simple" solution. What you have to do is the following:

- If a client connects to a worker, save the connection-id together with the worker-id and a potential additional identification-id in a global (=for all workers accessible) store (i.e. redis).
- If a client gets routed to another worker, use the store to look up which worker is reponsible for this client (either with the connection-id or with the additional identification-id and then hand it over to that worker (either with the nodejs-worker-master-worker-communication or via redis-pub-sub)

I habe implemented such thing with sock.js and an additional degree of complexity: I have two node.js servers with four workers each, so I had to use redis-pub-sub for worker/worker communication, because it is not guaranteed that they are on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks, @heinob. Did you have to hack source of sock.io to do this?

Comment: As I said, I did it with sock.js, because it seems to be much more stable than io. But I did not hack the source. Plain standard.

Comment: It handshakes but then as far as I remember it can't find transport. Basically I had to switch to using websockets protocol instead of XHR-polling (in which cases it would connect to different Node workers and thus have to reconnect) and use Redis pub-sub dispatcher to handle events. But ideally I wish Socket.io just worked for me. I'd have to experiment more.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there **is** a *simple solution*: using **Redis** to store sockets states.
Everything is explained in [Socket.IO documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO):

The default 'session' storage in Socket.IO is in memory (`MemoryStore`).

> The `MemoryStore` only allows you to deploy **socket.io on a single
>   process**. If you want to **scale to multiple process and / or multiple
>   servers you can use our RedisStore** which uses the Redis NoSQL database
>   as man in the middle.

So in order to change the *store* instance to `RedisStore` we add this:

```
var RedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis')
  , redis  = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis')
  , pub    = redis.createClient()
  , sub    = redis.createClient()
  , client = redis.createClient();

// Needs to be done after 'listen()'
io.set('store', new RedisStore({
  redisPub : pub
, redisSub : sub
, redisClient : client
}));
```

Of course you will need to have a redis server running.

Comment: It's working fine for me in both dev and prod. What issue do you have? Still no handshaking?